# Cant create file via suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to create a file via a restlet with code such as:

```
 /**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Restlet
 */
define(['N/file'], function (file) {
    var fileRequest = {
        name: 'test' + '.txt',
        fileType: file.Type.PLAINTEXT,
        contents: 'test',
        description: 'f',
        folder: 165
    };
    try {
        var resultingFile = file.create(fileRequest);
    }
    catch (ex) {
        debugger;
    }
    var fileId = resultingFile.save();
});
```

When i run this i receive an error at the file.create with the following message: 'Unexpected Error'.

Comment: Guess i wasn't as clear as i thought. I have those comments included. I just pasted here what i was trying to run in the script debugger to emulate. Question has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

With SuiteScript 2.0, you need to have a JSDoc comment block at the top of the file.

It looks like you're trying to create a custom module so at a minimum you will need:

```
/**
 *  @NAPIVersion 2.0
 *  @NModuleScope Public
 */
```

If you're trying to create a script for one of the standard script types, you'll need to specify that as well like this:

```
/**
 *  @NAPIVersion 2.0
 *  @NModuleScope Public
 *  @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
```

You'll also need to expose the appropriate entry point if you're doing this, like `pageInit` or `beforeLoad` depending on the script type.

NetSuite will prevent you from uploading SuiteScript 2.0 file if it doesn't have the appropriate JSDoc block or entry points.

Comment: If you are defining a custom module or a script, then you need to use `define` instead of `require` as well. You typically only use `require` for running some ad-hoc code in the debugger or the browser console.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh That was a very important point that quickly saved me a lot of headache.